# The effect of the order of observations on the distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, linear-model

Consider linear regression. It is known that if $Y \sim N_n\left(X\beta, \sigma^2 I_n\right)$, where $X$ is $n \times p$ of rank $p$, then
$$
\hat{\beta} \sim N_p\left(\beta, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}\right)
$$
(Seber, George A. F. and Lee, Alan J., "Linear Regression Analysis", 2nd Edition, 2003, John Wiley & Sons, Theorem 3.5 (i), p. 47.)

If I understand correctly, $n$ is the number of observations, and each observation consists of $p$ components. If this is the case, I would expect that the order by which the observations are listed should have no effect on $\hat{\beta}$'s distribution. And yet, if $Z$ is an $n\times p$ matrix that is obtained from $X$ by permuting $X$'s rows (i.e. by listing the observations in a different order), $Z^TZ$ is not necessarily the same as $X^TX$, and hence the two $\hat{\beta}$'s will not necessarily be equally distributed.

How can it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And yet, if $Z$ is an $n×p$ matrix that is obtained from $X$ by permuting $X$'s rows (i.e. by listing the observations in a different order), $Z^TZ$ is not necessarily the same as $X^TX$

Can you show some examples where your claim that they can differ is true?

Note that the $i,j$ element of $X^TX$ is $\sum_k x_{k,i}x_{k,j}$. This sum won't change when you alter the order of the $k$'s you're summing over.

You might try a few small examples and see what effect permutation of the rows of $X$ has.

Answer (score 2):

To make the same point as Glen_b but in a different way, we can prove that if $Z$ is a reordered $X$ then $Z^T Z = X^T X$. Specifically, if $Z$ can be obtained from $X$ by permuting $X$'s rows then there exists a permutation matrix $P$, such that $Z = PX$. All permutation matrices are orthogonal matrices, so $P^{-1} = P^T$ and hence $P^T P = I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then we have,
$$
Z^T Z = (PX)^T PX = X^T P^T P X = X^T I X = X^T X
$$
as required.